# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.Assignedrollno: line 4, column 1

Tags: trigger

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object:
>   Trigger.Assignedrollno: line 4, column 1

```
trigger Assignedrollno on student__c (before insert) {
    if(trigger.isbefore && trigger.isinsert){
       for(student__c s : trigger.new){      
           string Rollno =(string.valueof(s.createddate).right(2))+ '000' + (string.valueOf(s.Registration_no__c).right(2));
           s.Roll_No__c =  integer.valueof(Rollno);  

       }
    }
}
```

without createddate i'm getting only last 2 digits of Registration_no__c
Can anyone pls give me the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system fields are not populated in the before insert context hence `s.createddate` will be `null` and performing an operation on `null` object would result into

> Attempt to de-reference a null object

exception. You can instead use `System.Now()` or `DateTime.Now()` instead of `createddate`.

So your trigger code could be

```
trigger Assignedrollno on student__c (before insert) {
    if(trigger.isbefore && trigger.isinsert){
       for(student__c s : trigger.new){      
           string Rollno =(string.valueof(System.Now()).right(2))+ '000' + (string.valueOf(s.Registration_no__c).right(2));
           s.Roll_No__c =  integer.valueof(Rollno);  

       }
    }
}
```

If you still want to continue with the CreatedDate, then you will have to update the field in `after insert` context which would require an explicit `update` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Part #1 :

In Before Insert context, Created Date would be null - That is the reason for the Null Pointer exception

Part #2:

And without the CreatedDate, the '000' part would be omitted as you are trying to insert it as an "Integer" so initial zeroes are excluded and only the last two character of Registration is included.

Try adding them as a String, probably you would get those zeroes included and use System.Now to include CreatedDate instead.